# Warning: Division by zero in PHP on line 162

Tags: php

I have this error on my site:

> ERR (3): Warning: Division by zero  in
>   public_html/app/code/community/VES/PdfProProcessor/Pdf/include/table_frame_reflower.cls.php
>   on line 162

at that line I have the following code:

```
  $increment = 0;

  // Case 1:
  if ( $absolute_used == 0 && $percent_used == 0 ) {
    $increment = $width - $min_width;

    foreach (array_keys($columns) as $i) {
      $cellmap->set_column_width($i, $columns[$i]["min-width"] + $increment * ($columns[$i]["max-width"] / $max_width));
    }
    return;
  }
```

how I can solve this error?

Comment: what is the value of $max_width? print that and fix it

Comment: I think your dividing by 0 on line 162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  $increment = 0;
  $max_width or $max_width=1;

  // Case 1:
  if ( $absolute_used == 0 && $percent_used == 0 ) {
    $increment = $width - $min_width;

    foreach (array_keys($columns) as $i) {
      $cellmap->set_column_width($i, $columns[$i]["min-width"] + $increment * ($columns[$i]["max-width"] / $max_width));
    }
    return;
  }
```

Comment: I add your code and now I see something like this:

2017-09-30T07:25:03+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(OAuthException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Answer (score 1):

Your `$max_width` variable is either not assigned, or holds the value of zero.
If that does not appear to be the case, try `echo`ing this variable's value inside your `if` statement.